# First result from DB not showing when using while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pear, vtiger

I am creating a php script to generate reports based on data stored in SQL, The query is here:

```
$sql = $adb->query("SELECT firstname, lastname, policynumber, isatype, isaname, startdate, unitvalue, numberofunits, currentamount, date, newunitvalue, newnumberofunits, newcurrentamount
                                FROM vtiger_isa, vtiger_addisa, vtiger_contactdetails
                                WHERE vtiger_isa.relatedclient = vtiger_addisa.addrelatedclient
                                AND vtiger_addisa.addrelatedclient = vtiger_contactdetails.contactid
                                AND vtiger_isa.relatedclient = $clientid
                                AND vtiger_isa.policynumber = $polnum
                                AND vtiger_addisa.addrelatedclient = $clientid
                                AND vtiger_addisa.newpolicynumber = $polnum
                                ORDER BY date ASC"
                               );
```

This performs fine as I have tested by using `print_r($sql);` and the results I want are there. Although when I am looping through the results they do not show. I have tested with different clientid's and the first result seems to missed out.

```
<b> New Figures:</b>
 <table  style="width:100%">
 <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Unit Value (P)</th>
    <th>Number of Units</th> 
    <th>Total Value (£)</th>
    </tr>
 <?php
while ($sql->fetchInto($row)) {
    ?>
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['newunitvalue'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['newnumberofunits'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['newcurrentamount'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}?>
 </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute the code in the phpMyAdmin SQL Section? Or can you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using the `fetchInto()` method. I using the following example:

```
<?php
$sql = $adb->query("...");

foreach($sql as $row){
   ?>
   <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['newunitvalue'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['newnumberofunits'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['newcurrentamount'];?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
}
?>
```

This is working every time. Try it out.